# Por qué cuando hago scroll en el TableView las imágenes hacen AutoSize y vuelven a su tamaño natural?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

Cuando cargo la aplicación por primera vez se ven todas las imagenes del tableview de un mismo tamaño y sin problemas, de esta manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando hago scroll sobre el tableview, las imagenes vuelven a su estado natural, no entiendo por qué ocurre esto... Quedan así.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código donde agrego la imagen en CELL en el tableview

```
let reference = user?["Logo"] as? String ?? ""
        let fileUrl = NSURL(string: reference)

        let placeholderImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "negociophoto") //placeholder if wanted

        cell.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: fileUrl as URL?, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)
        cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        cell.imageView?.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        cell.imageView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        cell.imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell.imageView?.frame = CGRect(x: 10,y: 0,width: 10,height: 10)
        cell.imageView?.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
```

Espero alguien sepa por qué ocurre esto, muchas gracias por todo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucioné, el problema era que estaba cargando imágenes a través de una url con SDWebImage y cargaban con el tamaño original de la imagen. Lo que hice fue lo siguiente. Transforme la imagen desde una url a un objeto imagen para poder darle atributos de tamaño.

```
cell.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: fileUrl as URL?, placeholderImage: placeholderImage,
                                    options: [],
                                    progress: nil,
        completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in

            guard let image = image else { return }

            cell.imageView?.image = self.resizeImage(image: image, newWidth: 50)

        })
```

Y esta es la función resizeImage que use para darle el tamaño a la imagen después de haberla cargado.

```
func resizeImage(image: UIImage, newWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newWidth))
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newWidth))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La verdad es que tu pregunta no es muy clara

Dentro de que método está ese código? en viewDidLoad?

Es posible que necesites ubicarlo en otro lugar de tu código, como tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Está ahí donde tu dices, funciona todo correctamente, sólo que cuando hago scroll y desaparece una cell y vuelvo a verla después, la imagen cambia de tamaño, como si se hubiese cargado de nuevo pero en su tamaño real. Yo quiero que mantenga un mismo tamaño siempre.

Comment: La zona de respuestas no es espacio para hacerle preguntas al OP de su publicación

Answer (score 0):

Puedes enseñar el método `cellForRowAt`entero? 
Normalmente cuando las celdas cambian de forma imprevista después de hacer scroll es porque hay condiciones que no están completas. 
Un ejemplo

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! MyCell
        if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
            labelA.textColor = .blue
            labelB.textColor = .black
        } else {
            labelA.textColor = .black
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Aquí aunque se haya definido antes el color de `labelB`si en un **if** le cambiamos el color, en el **else** si no lo definimos puede haber inconsistencias y pasar cosas como la que te está pasando a ti. En tu caso, al ser el tamaño de la imagen, y al no ver el método entero, no sé si eso te puede ayudar.